# where msaccess vba

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

why the following msaccess vba statement fails when add the where statement?
I want to check if the field has value

```
Set rsMySet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("PivotTblInvDepts")

'Start the count at the position number of the first column-oriented field
'Remember that Recordsets start at 0
    For i = 3 To rsMySet.Fields.Count - 1
'*********************************************************************************************************************
'Use the recordset field.name property to build out the SQL string for the current field
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO TabularDepts ([Depts], [Code], [Description], [Qty])" & _
    "SELECT" & "'" & rsMySet.Fields(i).Name & "'" & " AS Dept," & _
    "[PivotTblInvDepts].[Code],[PivotTblInvDepts].[Description]," & _
    "[" & rsMySet.Fields(i).Name & "]" & _
    "FROM PivotTblInvDepts;" & _
    "WHERE" & " (rsMySet.Fields(i).Name)>0"
```

Comment: Why are you calling the same table in a VBA recordset and using it in an insert query and especially since you loop through column names, not actual records? Consider creating an append as a stored query object and call it with `DoCmd.OpenQuery`.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the `;` in `FROM PivotTblInvDepts;`.

Also you need space at the end of the previous line. `"[" & rsMySet.Fields(i).Name & "]" & _` should be `"[" & rsMySet.Fields(i).Name & "] " & _`.  Likewise, make sure to add a space  so that you do no result in `FROM PivotTblInvDeptsWHERE`

Your current SQL reads something like this

```
INSERT INTO TabularDepts ([Depts], [Code], [Description], [Qty])
SELECT '<data>' As Dept,
[PivotTblInvDepts].[Code],[PivotTblInvDepts].[Description],
[<data>]
FROM PivotTblInvDepts;
WHERE <condition>
```

After removing the `;`, the insert will be cleaner.

Comment: additionally the where itself will evaluate to WHERE rsmySet.Field(i).name>0.  I think the OP needs to move the " after the & to just before the > and precede it with a &. `"WHERE" &  (rsMySet.Fields(i).Name)&">0"`